# Live text reader with highlighting in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a program which writes to a .log file as it is installing software.
Some of the lines will contain either WARNING or FAILED.

What I would like, is a window in my program which will read the .log file and display the content into this window as it is being written too.  Any lines which contain WARNING or FAILED in them are highlighted yellow/red.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a FORM (I used VB 2010) and add this code.
it will write 3 lines on the form in 2 colours.
It might get you on your way. Ask MSDN help for each function that is new to you.

```
 Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    Dim chRs(0) As CharacterRange
    Dim sbRs(0) As SolidBrush
    Dim flRs(0) As SolidBrush
    Dim blueBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Blue)
    Dim whiteBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.White)
    Dim redBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Red)
    Dim EditFont As New Font("Courier New", 9)
    Dim stringFormat As New StringFormat
    Dim aRectangle As Rectangle
    Dim RectHeight As Integer = 20
    For i = 1 To 3
        Dim txt As String = "a string " & CStr(i)
        If i = 2 Then
            sbRs(0) = blueBrush
        Else
            sbRs(0) = redBrush
        End If
        flRs(0) = whiteBrush
        chRs(0) = New CharacterRange(0, txt.Length())
        Dim chRsa As Array = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(CharacterRange), 1)
        Array.Copy(chRs, 0, chRsa, 0, 1)
        aRectangle = New Rectangle(0, CInt((i - 1) * RectHeight), ClientRectangle.Size.Width, RectHeight) ' x, y, w, h 
        stringFormat.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(chRsa)
        Dim stringRegions As Array = Array.CreateInstance(GetType([Region]), 1)
        stringRegions = e.Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(txt, EditFont, aRectangle, stringFormat)
        Dim measureRect1 As RectangleF = stringRegions(0).GetBounds(e.Graphics)
        Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
        g.FillRectangle(flRs(0), measureRect1)
        g.DrawString(txt.Substring(chRs(0).First, chRs(0).Length), EditFont, sbRs(0), CSng(measureRect1.X), CSng(measureRect1.Y))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You aren't disposing your objects.

Comment: Which object should be disposed off? The only one I can think of would be the Graphics object, but I don't create it, just use it!

Comment: Basically, anything that implements *IDispose*: Brushes and Fonts, even StringFormat.  A `Using(...){}` block only works on disposable objects, so it will dispose of it for you at the end of the block, and is a good way to make sure your objects are cleaning up after themselves.  In your example, you wouldn't dispose of the Graphic object, because you're right, you didn't create it.